# MongoDB: How to query nested array specific elements?

Tags: mongodb

I've a complex collection in `MongoDB`. In this, I want to query `departments` data based on the `subDeptName`. I used query like below `db.getCollection('users').find({"departments.subDeptName" : "Java"})`, but its fetching all the array elements of the department. I only wants to query such department where `"subDeptName" : "Java"`. How can we do that ?

```
{
    "firstName" : "John",
    "lastName" : "Kerr",
    "email" : "john.kerr@gmail.com",
    "countryName" : "USA",
    "usRestrictionSw" : "N",
    "status" : "Active",
    "effDate" : ISODate("2012-08-24T01:46:33.000Z"),
    "departments" : [ 
        {
            "subDeptCd" : "AB",
            "languageCd" : "en",
            "desc" : "Development Group",
            "subDeptName" : "Java",
            "status" : "Active"
        }, 
        {
            "subDivisionAlpha2Cd" : "KG",
            "subDivisionCd" : "B",
            "languageCd" : "ru",
            "desc" : "Testing Group",
            "subDeptName" : "Python",
            "status" : "Active"
        }, 
        ..........
        ..........
        ..........
        ..........
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.getCollection('users').find({"departments.subDeptName" : "Java"})
```

Will match all users with a sub deperament java.

Easiest way to achieve the result you want is this:

```
 db.getCollection('users').aggregate([
           {
             $unwind: "$departments"
           },
           { 
             $match: {
                "departments.subDeptName" : "Java"
           }
 ])
```

Now you can also add a $project phase to get only the specific fields you want.

Comment: Thanks ! But How can we query this using Spring Data Mongo APIs?

Comment: Is there any way if we can get the count of this fetch elements as well ?

Comment: sorry but what do you mean by "count"? the amount of documents returned is also the count (?).

Comment: I mean, Count of departments too

Comment: Could you please suggest that option too in your code ?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:-

```
db.getCollection('users').find({"departments.subDeptName" : "Java"})
```

i have checked this on command line work fine. 
Please check your mongo version and mongo shell version

mongod --version (check mongo version)

mongo --version    // check mongo shell version.

And also check error log for have unother issue.

Comment: You did not followed my question, its pulling all the department array values

Comment: You use aggregate or not ?